# Expand information in flag-summary

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

After the new flag-options with detailed sub-reasons have been introduced, I think it is relevant that the flag-summary view is expanded accordingly.

Looking in my own list, I have flagged quite a few as off-topic. Most of these were probably due to lack of minimal understanding, ie. questions with no code and just a minimal explanation.

At any rate one of these flags got declined and I went back to check on the question to see why my flag was (considered) wrong. I couldn't immediately see it, but then I noticed a comment I had placed on the question when I flagged, checked the revisions, and the first revision was indeed a "I have these data and these requirements, what should I do?" So I'm guessing that I flagged this question as `Off-topic --> Must demonstrate minimal understanding` - but I can't verify that because my list only says `off-topic`.

Given that off-topic can mean anything from the question needing more work to the question belonging on another site I think it would be relevant to have the sub-reason specified in the flag list as well.