# No Suitable Reason to Recommend Close

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, vote-to-close

In reviewing low quality posts, I cannot see a [suitable option to close this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2596812).

It was closed as:

[image: Closure reason]

The available options are as follows.

[image: Close Options 1]

[image: Doesn't belong here]

[image: Off topic options]

Comment: Full close privileges include an "other" option so we can type a custom off topic message.  For flagging a default off topic option would probably be good

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree

Comment: I thought that users without full close permissions would see *Flagging > Off-Topic* rather than *Closing > Off-Topic*. Hmm.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta not anymore.  I'm pretty sure it shows "closing" now.  Flagging as "it doesn't belong here" is more of a non-vote close vote.  It just throws it to the close vote queue.

Comment: this is in the low quality review queue @MichaelPetrotta

Comment: @Michael We need a switch we can flip to remove our 3k privs so we can reproduce these things.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that <3k users can get in to the drill-down OT menu now.

Comment: Just found [Better flagging as off topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic).  I think it is a pretty close duplicate since it is a feature request asking to add this feature.

Comment: I am just shocked that such a carefully formatted paint image could receive downvotes!! ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close recommendation flag sends the question to the close votes queue in /review. Full 3k privs allow access to a shiny 'other' box, which allows a freehand reason. For you, not yet having CV privs, a simple OT flag will be sufficient to get the post attention from those that can close it.

[image]

Comment: Which OT flag does one use

Comment: The one you feel is most applicable. I can't see the example question, so I don't know about that, but choose the best one. It doesn't really matter, as long as it gets in front of those who *can* take action.

Comment: It was about translating a message that youtube shows up about copyright into three other languages.

Comment: Maybe the 'minimal understanding required' or the 'request for tools' reasons?

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but it's a hole in the process

Comment: @Skippy I agree, there is a hole.  Take a look at the dup I just added.  Looks like the custom reason doesn't even appear to the close voters, so it doesn't actually matter what you select.  Seems counter intuitive, but that's how it is design currently.