# How to flag way off topic questions

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, off-topic

I just flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128083/facebook-website-comments) as off topic.

I flagged it with the following reason, but I don't think this was quite the right reason for this question:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the
>   question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

I'm pretty sure that reason doesn't make sense for that question, but since that question is way off topic, I don't know what reason I should have used. What reason should be used for way off topic questions?

Comment: This type of question needs to be flagged with the "knucklebrain question" tag... I don't know why you didn't use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [there's no way to choose an off topic flag reason other than the canned responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so).

However, at this time, [the sub-reason when raising an off topic flag is not displayed anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic/188654#188654). This means all off topic flags (other than for migration) will be handled the same way, as close voters will only see "off topic".

If you want to raise an off topic flag for migration and your desired site isn't in the list, you can use a custom diamond moderator flag; just be sure your explanation is logical and well written. You should not use such flags for trying to close but not migrate an off topic question, as that can be handled by the community.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to write you own off-topic message (if you have enough rep to **close**, although not [when you are **flagging** - by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so)), so I think your action is perfectly valid if it is "way off-topic" and would be "corrected" in the review queue.

Actually, I think the reason you give is bang on for this question:

- It's a unclear what is being asked
- I *think* it's based on using the facebook api in OP's website... (hence programming related)

*However, it needs some (SSCCE) code in there to explain precisely what the OP is having trouble with.* :)

Update: the question is now closed as *"does not appear to be about programming"* (which I think is a very accurate close reason), and makes it clear that the OP should be more explicit about what they should change for it to be reopened (if, indeed, it is programming related)...