# Show sub reasons in close review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

Currently close vote review queue shows the top level
close reason in the header, but some close reasons, for
instance, off topic have very different sub reasons. For
instance, "demonstrate minimal understanding" is different from
"This question belongs on a different site in the stack exchange
network".

It would be nice if sub close reasons were also shown.

Comment: It would also be nice if we could filter on those sub-reasons.

Comment: Does it matter how other people voted? If it deserves to be closed, it deserves to be closed.

Comment: @Wooble Yes, it does matter how other people voted. If I can pinpoint the reason why a post needs to be closed without reading the entire thing, I can review faster.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic/188654#188654). These two requests need to go hand in hand, otherwise it becomes impossible to validly flag a post as off topic if there isn't an appropriate canned reason.

Comment: +1, I wrote up something very related to this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199627/131453

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existing votes are (and always have been) available on the close dialog that appears:

[image]

but yes: I can see how it may be very useful to know what the votes are *before* you decide to click a button. Consequently, from the next build, this information will be available to you! Since the reasons are in many cases quite verbose (and there is no "short form"), they are shown in the "more..." area:

[image]

If multiple reasons have been suggested, they will be displayed separately in the "more" area.

Because we care.

Comment: What if there is more than one reason chosen?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd see the edit a few moments ago. That worked fine before and after I tweaked it for the newer screenshot - it is just a bit clearer now.

Comment: Good job, looks like you do care! :)

Comment: The thing from the first screenshot displays something only if there was actually vote to close, not a flag to close. If the question was flagged for closing, does "(more)" still display which subreason was chosen by the flagger?