# Show the complete close reason in the Reopen Votes queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-reopen, custom-close-reasons

The [Reopen Votes queue](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/106289) shows the reason why the question was closed:

[image: Reopen Votes queue]

However, it only shows the generic reason "This question doesn't meet a Academia [sic] Stack Exchange guideline". If I navigate to [the question itself](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/177936/satirical-journals-for-the-arts-and-humanities), the complete (specific) close reason is shown:

[image: Closed question with complete close reason]

> **Closed.** This question is what we call a "[shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/112007)". It is currently not accepting answers.

I find it important to know the complete reason for closing before deciding whether the question should be reopened (i.e., whether that reason has been addressed). It seems that this has been requested before [for the Close Votes queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192634/643262), but not for the Reopen Votes queue.

**Can the complete (specific) close reason be shown in the Reopen Votes queue too?**

Comment: Similar answer from the announcement post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369362/1017231

Comment: This is especially annoying if one of the reasons you can give when you don't vote for reopening is "Original close reason(s) were not resolved." How can we know if that is the case?