# Why was my off topic flag declined?

Tags: support, specific-question, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455020/e-customer-behaviour-in-a-web-application) as off topic, because it's a shopping question. There's nothing fancy going on, just a straightforward request for a list of tools. The accepted answer is scarcely more than a pile of external links.

My flag was recently declined (not disputed), and I don't understand why. The question includes a remark that it had been cross-posted to Webmasters and subsequently closed (now deleted). I assume the Webmasters community closed it for the same reason I flagged it, but can't tell, since I don't have 10k on that site.

I don't care about the flag weight; I just want to understand why it wasn't correct. Please note that I'm under 3000 rep and this was a closure flag, which would've been a close vote if I had higher rep.

Comment: Not to mention, it was a question that was [closed and deleted on Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31993/e-customer-behaviour-in-a-web-application).

Comment: Both "e-commerce" and "google analytics" tags exist on SO, and it sounds to me like a good question that relates to both tags. I'm not clear on what you think is off-topic about the question?

Comment: @JohnnyBones It's a [shopping question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad). We have an explicit custom close reason on SO stating that these kinds of questions are not appropriate. As an aside, [if custom flag reasons were shown to VTCers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188106/better-flagging-as-off-topic) I suspect this would not have been declined.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName It's not actually a shopping question, or a recommendation question.  He's not asking for the best tool (that would be a recommendation).  He's asking for a list of all of them.  That makes it "too broad".  Still closeable though, just for a different reason.  (For the record, if I were handling the flag I would mark it as helpful, even though I would use a different close reason.)

Comment: @JohnnyBones Just because a tag exists doesn't mean anything relating to those tags is on topic.  There are lots of tags for things that aren't on topic, or lots of questions relating to a tag, but still outside of the topic scope that SO has defined (even if some other questions related to those tags would be in scope).  Regardless, this is a pretty poor question that should be closed for reasons unrelated to its topic.

Comment: It was declined automatically because of [reviews](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2807246).

Comment: @Servy A good point; there's even a comment to that effect, and it's certainly a valid reason to close the question. I picked the shopping reason because I read it as asking for the most popular ones: "I would like to know what are the main tools in the market".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question went through the Close Queue in /review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2807246.

As you can see, three people disagreed with your closure proposition and voted to leave it open. That kicked the question out of the queue and declined your flag.